# Export Bind-DLZ data to traditional named.conf?

Tags: bind, powerdns, named-conf

I'm looking to convert a Bind-DLZ based setup to a PowerDNS based setup. To do this, I would like to use the zone2sql tool that comes with PowerDNS. Sadly, this tool skips right over the DLZ defined zone in my `named.conf`. I have been searching for a script that will dump the DLZ database into traditional DNS files and a `named.conf` that references them, but have not had any luck.

Does such a tool exist? If so, would you be so kind as to link me to it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to simply `AXFR` the zone contents out of there?

Comment: I do not know. I'm relatively unfamiliar with Bind administration. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: My question is more about PowerDNS and the tools for it, as importing zone contents from `AXFR` seems more universal and cleaner than reading files. You can definitely get the zone contents from BIND (and most other nameservers) using `AXFR`, that is part of the standard zone transfer mechanism.  An example: `dig @nameserver example.com AXFR`, provided `allow-transfer` permits this. I may have a closer look at things on the PowerDNS side but atm I don't feel I can write a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method to extract the DNS information from the Bind-DLZ database is to use an [AXFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer) query for each "zone" in the database.

First, determine the zones stored in your database by connecting to it with whichever client is appropriate for your database type (e.g. `mysql`) and issuing the statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT zone FROM dns_records;
```

Where the `dns_records` table is the table that houses your DNS information.

Second, make sure the Bind server allows transfer requests from the host where you will be performing the extract. Edit your `named.conf` and adjust your options block accordingly (then restart Bind):

```
options {
  # Allow host 192.168.1.5 to issue AXFR queries to this server
  allow-transfer { 192.168.1.5; };
};
```

Third, for each zone in the list retrieved from your DLZ database, issue the following command:

```
$ dig AXFR @your-dns-server.example.com a.zone.com > a.zone.com.zonefile
```

Where "a.zone.com" is a zone from the list (e.g. "example.com"), and "a.zone.com.zonefile" is a file that will be created with the zone's entries.

Finally, use the [zone2sql](http://doc.powerdns.com/html/migration.html) tool to convert each of your zone files for the PowerDNS database.